# Anaconda Prompt : "The system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: anaconda, conda, prompt, anaconda3

Anaconda Prompt says "The system cannot find the path specified". Please refer to attached snapshot.

Also, I did not miss any installation step from this link:

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/

Please assist on this.

Image after Running Anaconda Prompt:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is likely due to a broken link to path present in the `activate.bat` script.

Run `conda init` and restart the Anaconda Prompt to reinitialize the conda environment and correct the path variables.